# SP 2010 Security Trim a Control for Permission Group

Tags: 2010, permissions, content-editor-web-part, security-trimming

I am working in Sharepoint 2010, I have a button in a content editor webpart on a page. I have set up two groups each with custom permission levels. Is it possible to security trim the webpart so that it only displays for people in the first group and not in the second group? Can I use security trimming with custom permission levels, or do I have to use OOTB levels? Any suggestions or tips for how best to accomplish this are appreciated.

Comment: You can [use javascript to check whether a user is part of a group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122139/check-if-current-users-belongs-to-sp-group-using-javascript-client-side-object-m) using `IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Audience Targeting to show and hide web parts based on

1. rules-based audiences(Global Audience),
2. SharePoint groups, and
3. distribution-list memberships

Note: this is not the same as security trimming, however, it may server your requirement. Check this [tutorial](https://lixuan0125.wordpress.com/2012/06/18/audience-targeting-sharepoint-2010/) on how to do it step by step

Comment: Hey Ahmed, this does hide the button. Is there a significant difference between audience targeting and security trimming? This is kind of a new subject to me, so I don't know whether it would be better to use one method or the other.

Comment: Security trimming basically means the user has no permission to access the object in question. So, for example, if you set a permission on a list, only users who have permission will be able to access and view it and more (depends on what permission level they have). However, audience targeting only controls the view of an object on a page, so the user might not be able to see the object, i.e. a list, however, she/he can access (from the site content)